# jquery id of distant parent of certain class

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have this HTML:

```
<div class="SomeParent" id="BlueParent">
  <div>
     <div class="Test">test</div>
  <div>
</div>
```

The div of class `Test` is actually deeply nested in the `SomeParent` container. What's the **fastest** way to get the id of the `SomeParent` class of which Test is a descendant. Is the `.parent()` the best way to do it?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps

```
$('.Test').closest('.SomeParent').attr('id');
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

I don't know if it would be any faster or slower than thecodeparadox's solution, however.

Comment: +1 It's always **faster** to iterate the parents instead of iterating every single child element.

Comment: Oh, yes, that does make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
$('div.SomeParent').has('div.Test').attr('id');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PGqR4/)**

Instead of parent you can use **[`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/)**.

Another choice is **[`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**:

```
$('.Test').closest('.SomeParent').attr('id')
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PGqR4/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the `<div.Test>` as a jQuery object then you could use `.closest()` rather than using `.parents()`. `.closest()` will stop once it hits the first occurrence of the selector you give it. `.parents()` on the other hand traverses up to the root of the dom and gives you back all found.

Comment: I think you confused `.parent()` with `.parents()`

Answer (score 1):

You could use parents() rather than parent() to specify the class of the parent element that you are searching for within the DOM tree of parents.

```
$(".Test").parents(".SomeParent").attr("id")
```